# Why are we not generally using egg in Buckwheat crêpe (or galette) but only in Wheat Flour crêpe?

Tags: flour, wheat, crepe, eggs

I was doing so research over the internet to know why egg are typically use in wheat flour crêpe but not in Buckwheat crêpe. Is there's a reason for it or it is just a simple question of recipe ?

Comment: I have always seen eggs in buckwheat crepes (look for *Crêpes au Sarrasin* which is the French name for them)

Comment: I just looked at different buckwheat crepe recipes and they all had eggs in them. However, I often make crepes without eggs and use some chickpea flour mixed in with the regular flour. It works because of the flavor of the chickpea flour and the extra protein. Maybe buckwheat flour has the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

Eggs make crepes stronger, which makes them less vulnerable to tearing. It also adds some taste if you like eggs.

If you have a good frying pan then you don't need them at all. You can make crepes with next to any type of flower without eggs or any egg replacement. Pure buckwheat on the other hand does not have gluten and might be more fragile.

In my experience "galettes bretonnes" are always with eggs, water and buckwheat, but without white flower or milk. I expect here the eggs are especially in use to make the dough less fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Galette bretonnes traditionally just water and buckwheat, no egg. True, egg makes the crepe less fragile, but with a good pan and the batter the right consistency, eggs are not necessary.